# Handling id_token in ASP.NET Core API

Tags: reactjs, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, auth0

I'm implementing Auth0 with my ASP.NET Core 2.1 app with React front end.

After the user authenticates, I do get both an `access_token` and an `id_token`. I'm clear that I send the `access_token` in the header to gain access to my API methods but I'm not sure how to handle the `id_token`.

Do I place the `id_token` in the header as well? If so, what key do I use for it? I'm sending the `access_token` with the key `Authorization` -- see below.
[image]

Not sure how to send the `id_token` and would appreciate some pointers on this. Thanks.

Comment: You would use `id_token` to construct the User object in SPA application and `access_token` is used to access the API. So, you don't put the `id_token` in the header.

Comment: I would then need to decipher the `id_token` to read the claims and get user info. Do I use a library for that?

Comment: Yes, there would normally be a library for that. I haven't used Auth0 specifically, but this might help: https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js/v9

Comment: The library might help with things like constructing user object and refreshing the access token.

Comment: Just went over the Auth0 documentation and looks like I make a call to get user profile which returns the user object with all the pertinent information. Thank you!

Comment: Since you just posted comments, I up-voted them but if you post your response as an answer, I'll accept it so that you can get credit for your help. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `id_token` to construct the User object in SPA application and `access_token` is used to access the API. So, you don't put the `id_token` in the header.

There is a JavaScript library for Auth0 that can help with authentication/authorization tasks: [Auth0.js](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js/v9).

The library may help with constructing the user object and refreshing the access token.

Comment: Or in other words you use the `id_token` to communicate back to the Auth0 API.

Comment: I have a follow up question, described here in a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230383/sending-user-info-along-with-access-token