# Sending user Id along with access_token

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, auth0

I'm implementing Auth0 in my ASP.NET Core 2.1 app with React front-end.

Once the user authenticates, I get both an `access_token` and an `id_token`. I'm clear that the purpose of `access_token` is to grant access to my API methods. I also understand that the `id_token` provides user data which I can use in my front-end app.

The question/concern is about sending user data, such as `userId` to my backend when I make API calls. Other than including `userId` in the body of my `POST` request, is there another way to send it to my API method?

Prior to Auth0, I used a couple of other solutions and the `JWT token` I received from them always included `userId`, `username`, etc. I thought this was a more secure approach because even though one can see what's in a `JWT token`, the signature allows us to make sure the data is not temperered with.

Even though my API calls are secured through `SSL`, I feel including the `userId` of the person who's making the API call in the body of my request is less secure compared to sending it through a `JWT token`.

Am I missing something here or do we indeed send the `userId` through the regular means in an API call i.e. in the body of a `POST` call or in the query string of a `GET` call?

Comment: The information about the user is retrieved from the access token. You just have to specify what claims you want to get from the identity provider by specifying scopes, such us `openid profile`. Then the claims would normally be accessed using `User.Claims` in the api project. The `sub` claim is the user id.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Good question man, i was going through the same problem last week and finally figured it out using the same `JWTAccessToken`.

The catch is in adding the *UserId* of the authenticated user as a claim when generating an access token which you can retrieve in the server.

**Adding Claims To Access Token**

Add the user's id to your list of claims first.

```
List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim("UserId", user.Id.ToString()));
```

Then generate an access token.

```
SecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                        issuer: {YOUR_ISSUER},
                        audience: {YOUR_AUDIENCE},
                        claims: claims,
                        notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
                        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60),
                        signingCredentials: credentials
                     );
```

Am assuming you already know how to perform the steps before reaching this final token generation as deducted from your prowess of `oAuth` and `JWT` shown above in your question.

**Retrieve Claim From Access Token**

To read a *UserId* from their access_token, let's create a couple of helper/extension methods to help us in reading an access_token from the `RequestContext` of a controller.

```
public static string GetUserId(this ControllerBase controller)
{
    string securityKey = "{YOUR_SECURITY_KEY}";
    SymmetricSecurityKey key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(securityKey));
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler token_handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    var tokenValidationParams = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = key,
        ValidateLifetime = false
    };

    string bearer = controller.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Replace("Bearer", string.Empty).Trim(' ');

    List<Claim> claims = token_handler.ValidateToken(bearer, tokenValidationParams, out SecurityToken token).Claims.ToList();

    Claim userClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "UserId");

    if(userClaim != null)
    {
        return userClaim.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Invalid AccessToken. UserId claim not found");
    }
}
```

**How To Use**

Let's now use this to get the *UserId* in any of our controllers:

```
[Authorize]
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string userId = this.GetUserId();

        // --> continuing code goes here.
    }
}
```

Comment: I was actually speaking within the context of Auth0 service which generates the tokens. Nevertheless, I appreciate your answer and accepted it. Having said that it is possible in Auth0 service to add custom claims to the `access_token` through "Rules". I was able to include userId, first name, last name and user's email address to the `access_token`.

Comment: Auth0 is generating the access_token so the first part of your answer is irrelevant.  As for the second part of your answer, the JwtBearer authentication handler will do all of this for you and the claims will be available on the ClaimsPrincipal `HttpContext.User` (referenced in `ControllerBase.User`).  `UserId` can be accessed in a controller by a simple call to `var id = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "userId");`.  This should not be an accepted answer.